# Datatables Search(multiple values for single column) not working if the values contain space character

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am implementing a web application using datatables(for table view). where I need to add search feature against some columns. Now user may want to look for multiple values in a column at a same time. For example if the column name is place. The user may ask for place with value tokyo and london at a same time.

To implement this i am referring 
https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html

It is working fine if the search string does not contain space in it.
for Eg. tokyo|london is giving proper result set as they do not contain space.
but when i am searching with tokyo|london|San Francisco. It is not giving proper result as San Francisco contains space in it.

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: When you used the example you referenced did you turn off Smart Search?  I was able to search `london|tokyo|san francisco` just fine with only regex.

Comment: Thanks  K Thorngren, It worked. The smart search option was not unchecked. Can you help me out in understanding 

1.  why it was not working when smart search option was checked.
2. and How datatables modifies the string when smart search is checked.

Comment: The [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API docs discuss how Smart search works.  General recommendation is to turn off Smart Search if using regex search.